# finding out the number in a set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I establish, on click, which order an element is within a set, so if I click the third element in a set, I get a three?

Here is a jsfiddle example -> http://jsfiddle.net/vtt3d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.index()` function to get it's index relative to it's siblings (starting at 0). [See updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/vtt3d/3/)

Answer (score 4):

If you want the position of the element in the exact set that was used to bind the click handler;

```
var set = $('#set a').click(function(){
    alert(set.index(this) + 1);
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtt3d/2/

If you want the position in the set of elements which match the selector *at the time the click event was dispatched*;

```
$('#set a').click(function(){
  alert($('#set a').index(this) + 1);
  return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtt3d/10/

See the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index) method

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/index/

```
$('#set a').click(function(){
  alert($('#set a').index($(this)) + 1);
  return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vtt3d/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$( '#set a' ).on(
   'click',
   function(  )
   {
      alert('Index: ' + $('#set a').index( $(this) );
   }
);
```

This is a zero based index. It will return the index position where 0 is the first position. If you want a more human-readable version add one the the returned index.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: That is syntactically incorrect. You should have http://pastebin.com/QswSDxGw. `li` is meaningless.

Comment: You can be sure this alerts `-1` since `this` is an `<a>` element that is **never** apparent in a set of `<li>` elements.